# Add or remove Folder RoleAssignments not valid error

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, flow, power-automate

Having trouble with adding or removing Role Assignments on SharePoint document folders using REST API through Power Automate.

Process is to copy a Template folder with subfolders. Of which, 2 subfolders need unique permissions to prevent unwanted user access.

I believe `BreakRoleInheritance` is being broken properly prior
Sent POST via Send HTTP request via SharePoint:

```
_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/SHOW FOLDERS/2017 Budgets/01 January/SHOW20')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
```

Sample command sending DELETE via HTTP to remove a SP Group with ID of (6) from folder:

```
_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(‘Shared Documents/SHOW FOLDERS/2017 Budgets/01 January/SHOW20')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/getbyprincipalid(6)
```

Error output:

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "The expression \"web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(‘Shared Documents/SHOW FOLDERS/2017 Budgets/01 January/SHOW20')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/getbyprincipalid(6)\" is not valid.\r\nclientRequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\r\nserviceRequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\",
  "source": "https://xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/FILETRANSFER/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%E2%80%98Shared%20Documents/SHOW%20FOLDERS/2017%20Budgets/01%20January/SHOW20')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/getbyprincipalid(6)",
  "errors": [
    "-1",
    "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Fixed my issue by fixing a typo.  Must have did a cut and paste badly.

Comment: On the DELETE command, the single quote before Shared Documents was the wrong character.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

1. Break Inheritance for the folder:

```
method: POST, content-type:application/json;odata=verbose

_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('TestLibrary/2019')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
```

2. Grant a SharePoint group with id=19 Contribution permission to the folder:

```
method: POST, content-type:application/json;odata=verbose

_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('TestLibrary/2019')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=19,roledefid=1073741827)
```

roledefid for Permission Levels are as follows:

1073741829, Full Control

1073741827, Contribute

1073741826, Read